# Lime Survey - geolocation response (city, country) params returns in end url

Tags: javascript, geolocation, limesurvey

LimeSurvey - click survey url, asks the user to allow or block location

ie. geolocation script run & return the current city & country in the end url.

It is possible or not. Below is my script, how to implement this in lime survey.

Any Suggestions, please

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

  var geocoder;

  if (navigator.geolocation) {
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(successFunction, errorFunction);
  } 

   function initMap(){
    }

   //Get the latitude and the longitude;
   function successFunction(position) {
  var lat = position.coords.latitude;
  var lng = position.coords.longitude;
   codeLatLng(lat, lng)
 }

 function errorFunction(){
alert("Geocoder failed");
}

function codeLatLng(lat, lng) {

alert("Latitude: "+lat);
alert("Longtude: "+lng);

geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latlng}, function(results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
  //console.log(results)      
    if (results[1]) {
     //formatted address                
     alert(results[0].formatted_address)         
    //find country name
    for (var i=0; i<results[0].address_components.length; i++) {
      for (var b=0;b<results[0].address_components[i].types.length;b++) {

        //there are different types that might hold a city admin_area_lvl_1 usually does in come cases looking for sublocality type will be more appropriate
            if (results[0].address_components[i].types[b] == "administrative_area_level_1") {
                //this is the object you are looking for
                city= results[0].address_components[i];
                break;
            }
            if(results[0].address_components[i].types[b] == 'country'){
              country = results[0].address_components[i];
              break;
            }
      }
    }        
    //city data
    alert(city.short_name + " " + city.long_name)
    //country data
    alert(country.short_name + " " + country.long_name)

    } else {
      alert("No results found");
    }
  } else {
    alert("Geocoder failed due to: " + status);
  }
});
 }   </script> 
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_KEY&callback=initMap"
type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Any help? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your code work (else : review your code first). I spoke only for LimeSurvey part.

1. Create a multiple text question type :

   - code GEO
   - Add 2 sub question code CITY and CONTRY
2. Add the class (using advanced settings) `hidden` then the question are not shown.
3. Deactivate HTML editor and put your script inside a [jquery ready](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) (alternate solution use [addScriptToQuestion](http://extensions.sondages.pro/questions-updating-and-managing/addscripttoquestion-easily-add-javascript/) plugin)
4. Add a space or a line feed after each `{` you have in your js code (and a space before each `}` )
5. replace you last alert (where you have city.data and coutry.data) by

   - `$("#answer{SGQ}CITY").val(city.short_name + " " + city.long_name);` for city
   - `$("#answer{SGQ}COUNTRY").val(country.short_name + " " + country.long_name);` for country
6. You can use {GEO_CITY} and {GEO_COUNTRY} in the survey (after this page)
7. Then you can use it in your url `http://example.org/?city={GEO_CITY}&country={GEO_COUNTRY}`

Using LimeSurvey 2.50 and up version (else need some javascript to hide the question)

Comment: Denis, you have a typo in your second selector - should be $("#answer{SGQ}COUNTRY")

Comment: Yep, fixed. But looking at the original js code : unsure it work here ;)

Comment: Denis, thank you so much, it is possible to store the city, country in lime db answer table when i submit the survey.

Comment: @bashirudeenahmad : yes ... the code store the city and contry in the db. In the 2 sub-questions .... It's the exact purpose of this code .... Here : i'm really unsure your code work (in LS or not).

Answer (score 1):

This abbreviated version works for me when placed in the source of a hidden multiple-short-text question as Denis suggests:`

```
var geocoder;

if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(successFunction, errorFunction);
} 

//Get the latitude and the longitude;
function successFunction(position) {
    var lat = position.coords.latitude;
    var lng = position.coords.longitude;
    codeLatLng(lat, lng)
}

function errorFunction(){
    console.log("Geocoder failed");
}

function codeLatLng(lat, lng) {

    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
    geocoder.geocode({ 
    'latLng': latlng },
    function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            if (results[1]) {
                for (var i=0; i<results[0].address_components.length; i++) {
                    for (var b=0;b<results[0].address_components[i].types.length;b++) {
                        // Find city name
                        // There are different types that might hold a city
                        // "locality" works for most of North America
                        // See here for types - https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro
                        if (results[0].address_components[i].types[b] == "locality") {
                            //this is the object you are looking for
                            city= results[0].address_components[i];
                            break;
                        }
                        // Find country name
                        if(results[0].address_components[i].types[b] == 'country'){
                            country = results[0].address_components[i];
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }        
                // City data
                //console.log(city.short_name + " " + city.long_name);
                $("#answer{SGQ}CITY").val(city.long_name);
                // Country data
                //console.log(country.short_name + " " + country.long_name);
                $("#answer{SGQ}COUNTRY").val(country.long_name);
            } 
            else {
                console.log("No results found");
            }
        } else {
            console.log("Geocoder failed due to: " + status);
        }
    });
}
```

`